# Stop form submit after page refresh with DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I use `request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response)` method in my controller !! I am in trouble. (I know that dispatcher make internal redirect, a forward reuses the current request), when I fill in a form and send request to controller that computes some logic and after forward to some simple page. If I push F5 in browser on my simple page (refresh page) my request will perform again. How to prevent this situation ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RequestDispatcher` will keep request attributes and forward page with same request, that is why if you refresh page controller gets same request and process it again. Use `SendRedirect` instead.